# Could we add a tag for the Procreate App?

Tags: discussion, tags

Procreate is doing very well, today it was [the 37th top US grossing app in the App Store.](https://sensortower.com/ios/us/savage-interactive-pty-ltd/app/procreate/425073498/) I would like to receive alerts when a Procreate question comes up, and as far as I can tell will need it to have a tag, to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a [procreate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procreate) tag to your question.  You should be able to use it now.

Answer (score 5):

When proposing new tags, please also propose texts for the tag descriptions so the community can improve on those to have a common understanding.

Having said that: tags should be used to add value to a question by providing additional categorization/grouping. Any question about Procreate will already have the application name in the question somewhere, so also having a tag doesn't provide a lot of value. Also, we currently have exactly two questions mentioning Procreate, and the older one isn't actually about Procreate as such. So I doubt that there really is a need for a new tag on this *currently*.

Comment: I am a consumer, not a coder, but yes, I have already started on the tag info for Procreate, counting on the tech community to fill in gaps. You may be right that this is a stagnant tag from the get go. Hope springs the eternal.

Comment: @LaurentR. Please add your proposal as an answer here, so people can contribute

Comment: Will do...  working on it...  Thanks all for advising, I was unsure how to proceed...